# Javascript Cookie - Countdown

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have an issue with some JS code.

I'm trying to get a countdown to start at a random number between 2 points (in this example 50 & 60) and countdown at random intervals. If the user refreshes, I want the countdown to continue from where it was last at before the refresh. I've managed to get so close but now (especially in FF) I keep getting (NaN) as the output.

Can someone please save me from smashing my laptop up?? :)

Thanks

```
<script> 
    var minSpaces = 50; //Minimum spaces to start with 
    var maxSpaces = 60; //Maximum spaces to start with 
    var maxDecTime = 6000; //Max time interval between decrements 
     var minDecTime = 300; //Min time interval between decrements 
    var redirectWhenDone = 0; //Redirect = 1 set to 0 for no redirect 
    var stopSpaces = 3; //Number it will stop at if not using redirect 
    var redirectLocation = 'http://www.google.com'; 

    if(document.cookie) {
        maxSpaces = parseInt(document.cookie);
        minSpaces = parseInt(Math.max(maxSpaces-5, 1));
    }
    var spaces = Math.floor(Math.random()*(maxSpaces-minSpaces+1)+minSpaces); 
    function updateSpaces() { 
        spaces--; 
        document.cookie = spaces+'; expires=Thu, 2 Aug 2015 20:47:11 UTC; path=/'; 
        document.getElementById('spaces').innerHTML =  
            '<span style="color:orange;">('+spaces+')</span> orders left!'; 
        var intvl = Math.round(Math.random()*maxDecTime) + minDecTime; 
        if(spaces>stopSpaces){ 
            setTimeout(updateSpaces, intvl); 
        } 
       else {//No spaces left, redirect! 
            if(redirectWhenDone==1) { 
                window.top.location = redirectLocation; 
            } 
}} 
    window.onload=updateSpaces; 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `sessionStorage` to hold some JSON and `setTimeout`

```
function randomInt(min, max) {
    return min + Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1));
}

function randomCountdown(current, interval) {
    var minStart = 50, maxStart = 60,
        minInterval = 300, maxInterval = 6000;
    var json = JSON.parse(window.sessionStorage.getItem('randomCountdown') || '{}');
    current = current || json.current || randomInt(minStart, maxStart);
    interval = interval || json.interval || randomInt(minInterval, maxInterval);
    window.sessionStorage.setItem('randomCountdown', JSON.stringify({
        current: current,
        interval: interval
    }));
    if (--current) {
        console.log('countdown', current, interval);
        // do whatever
        window.setTimeout(
            function () {randomCountdown(current, interval)},
            interval
        );
    } else {
        console.log('done');
    }
}

randomCountdown(); // start
```

Comment: I really appreciate the reply but I'm a little confused (and heavily stupid) - am I right in assuming that the above code needs to be placed inside <script></script> tags? if so I tried that and nothing happens. thanks again

Comment: The lines `console.log` and `// do whatever` need to be changed to the action you want, `--current` is decrementing by `1` each iteration. This code was so you could see an example of it resuming a countdown in console